# How to capture partial page contents with phatomjs or casperjs

Tags: javascript, pdf, phantomjs, screenshot, casperjs

How can we, capture a partial page content using phantomjs or casperjs.
I have seen that with

1. Phantomjs:

we can use page.clipRect

```
var clientRect = document.querySelector(selector).getBoundingClientRect();
page.clipRect = {
            top: clientRect.top,
            left: clientRect.left,
            width: clientRect.width,
            height: clientRect.height
        }
 };
 page.render(out.png);
```

2. casperjs

we can use :

```
casper.capture(String targetFilepath, [Object clipRect, Object imgOptions])
  or
 casper.captureSelector(String targetFile, String selector [, Object imgOptions])
```

but all the codes mentioned above work only with with images(jpg, png, ect) , not with pdf.

How can I capture a partial page content to render an pdf?

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours googling, I come out with no helpfull answer. It seems that neither casperjs or phantomjs have properties to handle this. I may be wrong, any correction will be appreciate.

To workaround this, i have seen that you have to hide all other selector in the dom and keep the one we want to render.

In your evaluate() method, you have to do:

1. Phantomjs

   ```
   page.evaluate(function (){
    $("#maps").appendTo('body');
    $('body > :not(#maps)').hide();
   })
   ```

then

```
page.render('out.pdf');
```

2. casperjs

   ```
   casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
   $("#maps").appendTo('body');
   $('body > :not(#maps)').hide();

   });
   ```

Any other solution will be appreciate.